# Delphi - Access Violation no formulário de login

Tags: delphi, login, microsoft-access, debug

Galera estou com um problema, sou iniciante em *Delphi* e estou desenvolvendo um sistema de cadastros e consulta, ele está quase finalizado, estou fazendo a parte de login do sistema, onde somente usuários cadastrados vão ter acesso.

Mas ao digitar o usuário e senha e clicar em entrar está me dando o seguinte erro

> Raised exception class $C0000005 with message - Acess violation at
>   0x008ebfd5: read of address 0x000001a0

[image: Access Violation]

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda ai? Pesquisei e vi que este erro é causado quando utiliza um objeto que não foi instanciado ou que já foi destruído, fiz o debug e ele me retorna a linha 37 que contém:

> with dtm.fdquery_Login do

```pascal
unit Unt_Login;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons;

type
  Tfrm_Login = class(TForm)
    edt_Usuario: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    edt_Senha: TEdit;
    Label2: TLabel;
    bbtn_Entrar: TBitBtn;
    bbtn_Cancelar: TBitBtn;
    procedure bbtn_EntrarClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edt_SenhaChange(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frm_Login: Tfrm_Login;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Unt_Dtm;

procedure Tfrm_Login.bbtn_EntrarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with dtm.fdquery_Login do
  begin
    Close;
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tb_Usuario WHERE user_login = :login AND user_senha = :senha');
    ParamByName('login').AsString := edt_Usuario.Text;
    ParamByName('senha').AsString := edt_Senha.Text;
    Open;

    if RecordCount > 0 then
    begin
      if (Time >= StrToTime('00:00:00')) and (Time < StrToTime('11:59:59')) then
      begin
        Application.MessageBox('Olá :bom_dia_nome_usuario bom dia, seu acesso ao sistema foi liberado', 'Seja bem vindo(a)', MB_OK);
        ParamByName('bom_dia_nome_usuario').Value := dtm.fdquery_Loginuser_nome.AsString;
      end;

      if (Time >= StrToTime('12:00:00')) and (Time < StrToTime('17:59:59')) then
      begin
        Application.MessageBox('Olá :boa_tarde_nome_usuario boa tarde, seu acesso ao sistema foi liberado', 'Seja bem vindo(a)', MB_OK);
        ParamByName(':boa_tarde_nome_usuario').Value := dtm.fdquery_Loginuser_nome.AsString;
      end;

      if (Time >= StrToTime('18:00:00')) and (Time < StrToTime('23:59:59')) then
      begin
        Application.MessageBox('Olá :boa_noite_nome_usuario boa noite, seu acesso ao sistema foi liberado', 'Seja bem vindo(a)', MB_OK);
        ParamByName(':boa_noite_nome_usuario').Value := dtm.fdquery_Loginuser_nome.AsString;
      end;

      frm_Login.Close;

    end

    else
    begin
      Application.MessageBox('Usuário ou Senha inválidos', 'Dados inválidos', MB_OK + MB_ICONERROR);
      Exit;
    end;

  end;

end;

procedure Tfrm_Login.edt_SenhaChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edt_Senha.PasswordChar := '*';
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este problema ocorre porque `dtm.fdquery_Login` não foi criado, não existe, é igual a `nil`.

No Delphi os objetos devem ser instanciados antes de ser utilizados.

```
if dtm = nil then
  dtm := Tdtm.Create(Self);
```

Agora isto vale também caso os objetos não foram adicionados no formulário, aqueles que foram declarados como variáveis devem também ser instanciado.

```
dtm.fdquery_Login := NomeDaClasse.Create(Self);
```

E somente após isto, utilizar o `with dtm.fdquery_Login do`

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta Júnior, foi de grande ajuda!

Comment: Recomendo não usar `with`, a primeira vista pode até economizar na digitação mas em uma `procedure` grande o Delphi pode perder a referência e incluindo o `dtm.fdquery_Login` explicitamente fica mais claro o código para futura alteração.